# Copy single table from DB to DB

Tags: sql-server, database, copy, ssms

Running an old .ADB application connected to MS SQL Server 2005, with bad documentation and UI,so user messed up one client record, so now when searching client it doesn't appear, but on Project page it shows client when it's projects are sellected, and even can add new project on same client.

I restored database from backup on same server to REST (short for RESTORED) database, and in table e dbo.Firme that client record exists with IDFirme primary key 264.

How to copy just table dbo.Firme from REST database on same server to my WORK database through SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to copy table headers and records? This will do:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    NewDbName.dbo.NewTable
FROM    OldDbName.dbo.Firme
```

This will not copy primary keys nor other information